# Unable to save as dataset when apache superset sql query has jinja template parameters in it

Tags: apache-superset

Below is the SQL Lab Query with jinja template parameters, I have added parameters in the parameter window as {"fromDate":"2022-01-01", "toDate":"2023-01-01"} and able to run the query successfully, however when trying to save the dataset I am getting error. Please suggest

```
select source, contextid 
from items 
where created >= '{{ fromDate }}' AND created < '{{ toDate }}'
```

error message from the log

```
superset.exceptions.SupersetGenericDBErrorException: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "{{ fromDate }}"
LINE 16:  items.created_at >= '{{ fromDate }}'
```

Comment: Can you also share the defined parameters for the Jinja templates?